# Regex PHP: match only numbers except the number that follows a specific character

Tags: php, regex

After many temptatives I need some help. I have the following typical string:

```
a15c1-6,c15-21,c25
```

I would like to match all the numbers only **but not the number that follows 'a'** so the expected output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 21
    [4] => 25
)
```

**\d+** matches all numbers correctly, but I don't understand how to exclude the number **'15'**.

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/O0Yz8M).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex using negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!a)\d+\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL5eD5/1)

`(?<!a)` is negative lookbehind that fails the match if a number is preceded by letter `a`.

Comment: Sure? I tested it on www.regexpal.com but it does not match anything.

Comment: Check the demo link I provided in answer.

Comment: @Nicero: I think PCRE option is not working at regexpal.com. This regex is working well in PHP. Regex101.com is an online PHP/Python/JavaScript regex tester you can trust.